# Serial downvoting of my answers, need users to stop now

Tags: support

I  have a few (three or four) people who downvote my accepted, backed up, well-worded answers. I need them to stop as for one it keeps giving me notifications on my phone in the same way ones that I need to answer or respond to do, and for two it keeps impacting my reputation on this site dramatically. They don't do it often enough to trigger the serial downvoting reversal many times, they did it once and haven't since, but I find I lose maybe 6 rep. a day on average. Is there anything anyone can do? Please note, I asked this once an hour ago or so and it was downvoted. THIS IS A REAL ISSUE I AM HAVING AND IF YOU DISAGREE THEN COMMENT WHY, DO NOT DOWNVOTE THIS AGAIN AS I NEED AN ANSWER.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm glad you undeleted this. First of all, downvotes on meta cost you no rep. They simply mean that someone found that your question is not useful. Don't get worked up about it. Downvotes on the main site are no big deal but downvotes on meta are a non-issue.

That said, there has been no serial downvoting of your answers. You have had one downvote today, one yesterday, and three the day before. That's hardly a pattern! Also, on the questions I checked, people had left you comments explaining precisely why they downvoted. Why don't you address their concerns instead of complaining about it?

For example, your answer to https://askubuntu.com/q/498278/85695 reads like pure speculation. You have just now edited it (thanks) to add how you got your measurements but you are still not telling us what the hardware involved was and you are still extrapolating from one instance to a general rule. Your findings will likely be very different if you do the same test using a different NIC and driver. At least tell us what NIC and what driver you are using. It will also depend on the kernel your are running and a variety of other things.

Your answer to https://askubuntu.com/q/503510/85695 is not answering the actual question. You are talking about the machine's HDD while the OP was talking about the USB. You just suggested he ignore the errors and continue. Again, someone helpfully pointed that out to you and you responded by insulting them:

> listen, you are being a troll in the extreme. I solved his problem and gave an answer that gives the BEST POSSIBLE SOLUTION based on the situation –  sbergeron Sep 29 at 3:34

Your answer to [64 v amd64 distribution](https://askubuntu.com/q/512966/85695) is, once more, completely unsupported by any evidence and very simply wrong as was pointed out to you:

> "amd64" ISOs are for all x86-64 computers, not just Macs (of which modern ones are x86-64). "amd64+mac" are for Intel-based Macs. They're the same as the "amd64" but with an additional shim to install for the UFI bootloader Mac's have. –  Oli♦ Sep 23 at 6:59

You seem to think that this is a popularity contest. It isn't. People vote up correct answers and vote down incorrect ones. Your downvotes all seem very reasonable to me and all you had to do is edit your question and answer the comments and I'm sure they would have been converted to upvotes. Instead, you started insulting people.

So, if you want to stop receiving downvotes, address the issues raised in the comments and fix your answers. Nobody hates you, they are reacting to problems in your posts.

Comment: I had a series of downvotes by am(space to not notify him)anthethy and a couple that directly followed suit that were reversed and when I got downvotes on those posts I assumed it was more of the same and responded out of frustration mainly. Thank you for your very civil, objective answer.

Comment: @sbergeron note that you can't know who downvoted you. Not even mods have access to that information. You are assuming that the people who took the time to leave a comment pointing out a problem with your answer also downvoted. That is not necessarily the case, you might be barking up the wrong tree and attacking only those who tried to help you. Oh, and to notify a user, you need a `@` before their username and they need to have had something to do with the post your are commenting on.

Comment: maybe. Thanks for the help and your time

Comment: @terdon That's not entirely true. We can see vote patterns which are identifiable past a certain point. Check out the User→Mod→Info→Votes screen on Unix.se.

Comment: @Oli I know, I meant that even mods can't see individual votes cast.

Comment: that's an amazingly considerate answer.

Comment: @sbergeron, I've never tried to directly target your posts and, if you go back and check, you can see that each time that I cast a downvote I explained why with a comment.  Not everyone is right all of the time. There's no shame in admitting that.

Comment: I understand that now, however I have had a few times where the system has reverted downvotes against me and they were each time on posts you responded to or included each post you responded to so I pretty much assumed it was either you or someone else following your actions and trying to frame you, but the likelihood of the latter was very low so I assumed it was you. I truly do apologize for blaming you for that

Answer (score 10):

Terdon's answer is great. I'll just add a few things that are only available to moderators. We can see voting patterns, so if somebody hammers you with votes (in either direction), we're able to see who's doing it.

- There has only been one person who has ever engaged in serial downvoting against you.
- We asked them to stop (even though their votes had individual merit) and they did. This was back in September.
- Subsequent votes have been from other users.

I would posit that aside from a serious technical quality issue, drawing attention to it with SHOUTY META POSTS repeatedly (this is your fourth post on the subject, [despite the problem being explained to you already](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/12008/is-there-any-system-in-place-to-prevent-downvote-trolling)) is likely just going to attract even more downvotes.

There's no conspiracy against you. What is happening here applies to every Ask Ubuntu user. If you want fewer downvotes, post better answers.